# PIL assistance Python

Tags: python, tkinter, syntax-error, python-imaging-library

I am working on a simple program that lets the user re size a image. But I have come into a problem. When I try to open the image using `Image.open()` I get the following error:

`AttributeError: class Image has no attribute 'open'`

I have researched this and it is from assigning something to `Image` like making it into a variable. But I can not see in my code that I have done anything that assigns something to `Image`

Here is my code:

```
from PIL import Image
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
import ttk

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.pack(fill=BOTH)

        self.create_widgets()

   def create_widgets(self):
        self.tfr = Frame(self)
        self.tfr.pack(side=TOP)

    self.title = Label(self.tfr, font=("Arial", 20), text="Image Resizer")
    self.title.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=40)

    self.spacer = Frame(self.tfr, bg="black")
    self.spacer.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

    self.mfr = Frame(self)
    self.mfr.pack(side=TOP)

    self.brButton = ttk.Button(self.mfr, text="Browse", command=self.browse)
    self.brButton.pack(side=LEFT, padx=(0, 2), pady=2)

    self.diField = Label(self.mfr, text="File Path...", relief=SOLID, bd=1, width=25, anchor=W)
    self.diField.pack(side=LEFT)

    self.spacer2 = Frame(self, bg="black")
    self.spacer2.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

    self.bfr = Frame(self)
    self.bfr.pack(side=TOP)

    self.rButton = ttk.Button(self.bfr, text="Resize", width=41, command=self.resize)
    self.rButton.pack(side=TOP, pady=2)

def browse(self):
    supportedFiles = [("PNG", "*.png"), ("JPEG", "*.jpg,*.jpeg,*.jpe,*.jfif"), ("GIF", "*.gif")]

    filePath = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(filetypes=supportedFiles, defaultextension=".png", mode="rb")

    if filePath != None:
        photo = Image.open(filePath, "rb")
        size = photo.size
        print(size)
    else:
        pass

def resize(self):
    print("Resize")

root = Tk()
root.title("Image Resizer")
root.resizable(0,0)

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Can anyone shed light on why I am getting this error. Any help is greatly appreciated..

Comment: your Image.open :  If the mode argument is given, it must be “r”.

Comment: @KevinDTimm That is not what is causing this error. Before it even gets to reading the image file. It gives me ht error above.

Comment: Correct but it will be your next problem

Comment: This a good illustration why global imports are bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really avoid `from PIL Tkinter import *` for obvious reasons but if you must then you can use   `from PIL import IMAGE as img` to differentiate  from the `Tkinter Image`

Answer (score 2):

`Image` from `Tkinter` replaces the same from `PIL`.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent it from doing this.. And that is odd because I have made other GUI's using TKitner and PIL and I did not get such problem with the PIL Image.open()

Comment: I'd just replace `from PIL import Image` with `import PIL.Image` and use `PIL.Image.Image`. Edit: `Image.Image`.

Comment: I did and I got the following error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Image'`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Can you write that as a answer because it worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `ImageTk` instead:

```
from PIL import ImageTk # add to imports

# later on when loading selected image

photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = filePath)
size = photo.width(), photo.height()
print(size)
```